# How do I turn my pine editor indicator signals into alarms?

Tags: pine-script, indicator, pine-editor

I'm new to pine editor and I need your help. I want my indicator to send me what I set as alarm.
let me give an example

When my indicator gives a short/long transaction, it will send me an alarm with the tp, entry price, sl prices that I have set.
If the long signal comes:

coin =

long or short =

tp1=

tp 2=

sl=

I want them to fill in the alarm

You don't need to tell me with the code, if you just tell me how to do it with an example article, it will help you a lot, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `alert()` function together with the `str.tostring()` for that.

Here is an example from Tradingview's [blog](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/).

```
//@version=4
study("alert() with multiple symbols")
f_triggerRsi(_ticker)=>
    _r = rsi(close, 7)
    _x = crossover(_r,70)
    _y = crossunder(_r,30)
    _rt = barstate.isrealtime
    [_rsi, _co, _cu, _rt_bar] = security(_ticker, timeframe.period, [_r, _x, _y, _rt])
    _msg = _ticker + ", " + timeframe.period + ": "
    if _co and _rt_bar
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_rsi) + ") crossing up 70 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    else if _cu and _rt_bar
        _msg := _msg + "RSI (" + tostring(_rsi) + ")  crossing down 30 level"
        alert(_msg,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

plot(rsi(close, 7), "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.new(#9915FF,90), title="Background")

f_triggerRsi(syminfo.tickerid)
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:MSFT")
f_triggerRsi("FX:EURUSD")
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:TSLA")
f_triggerRsi("NASDAQ:PYPL")
```